# How can I read deleted sql entries in node.js

Tags: node.js, azure-mobile-services

I'm interested in reading deleted items from a SQL table. I have enabled softdelete, so the deleted column will be set to "true" if I delete an entry.

With node I do a read like this but it seems it is not returning deleted items. How can I read deleted items?

```
tableName.where( function(id) {
    return this.id == id && (this.deleted == true || this.deleted == false);
    }, elem.uuid).read().then....
```

Is query API filtering deleted items?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you need to set the includeDeleted property to true on the query object. A sample table definition to read deleted items from another table might look like:

```
var table = module.exports = require('azure-mobile-apps').table()
var queries = require('azure-mobile-apps/src/query')

table.read(function (context) {
    var query = queries.create('otherTable')
    query.includeDeleted = true
    return context.tables('otherTable').read(query)
})
```

If you want to read deleted items from the current table, the read operation would look like:

```
table.read(function (context) {
    context.query.includeDeleted = true
    return context.execute()
})
```

I have created an issue on the azure-query-js github repository for making this much easier - https://github.com/Azure/azure-query-js/issues/18